# ETC1 and Drawable

Tags: android

Is it possible to use ETC1 compressed images to use as a Drawable on Android? I am currently using ETC1 textures on the OpenGL context of a surface view. But I would also like to use them in my UI like a Drawable. Are there workarounds for this?

Comment: You could capture your screen and save it as a normal PNG or JPG.

Comment: You got me wrong.. I want to use a etc1 file as a Drawable to display it in an ImageView or similar.

Comment: OK. The answer is: **NO**, you can't (at least, natively - don't know if there's a library to let you load such files). That's why I suggested you an alternative. Android won't even load **standard SVGs** in ImageViews, without the use of a 3rd party library...